# Entity Framework Code First - determining data type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning `Entity Framework` using the code first approach. Take the example below, say I have a class `Employee`:

```
public class employee
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string fName { get; set; }
    public string lName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

It will automatically create the table using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for `string`, and `int` for `int`.

How do I control the `data type` and `data size` created in the database? (For example, I want to use CHAR(20) instead of just NVARCHAR(MAX)?)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<employee> Employees { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
        {
            mb.Entity<employee>()
                .Property(i => i.fName)
                .HasColumnType("char")
                .HasMaxLength(20);

            base.OnModelCreating(mb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I resolve this error: Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Comment: This code is a method that needs to exist within your custom context class that extends DbContext

Comment: @C.J.Sorry, should have placed the complete code. Like AlexC said,  you can enter that in your context class that inherits DbContext class.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Code First Data Annotations, or use the fluent api. Which I definitely prefer.

For the fluent api, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591617.aspx). 
Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872483/entity-framework-mapping) for a more simple and working stackoverflow example ;-).