# Entity Framework simple foreign key setup creates ugly database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have seen a ton of examples here but for some reason my setup is creating a really disgusting looking database.

I have a company with an id, the company can have many users, and users can have one company. I thought about simply just giving the company a `List<User>` and letting the compiler make the database, but in code from a `User` I need to references their company.

I followed this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx#Relationships,%20Navigation%20Properties,%20and%20Foreign%20Keys), my code is missing the virtual on `Company` as a test, nothing changes.

Here is my minified code:

```
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyPK { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser RootUserFK { get; set; } = null;
        public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int CompanyPK { get; set; }
        public Company Company{ get; set; }
    }
```

My resulting database for the user has `CompanyPK, Company_CompanyPK, Company_CompanyPK1` which is not a good looking database at all. Also internally the database doesn't generate a table linking the Company's many users back to the company.

Comment: This sounds code first, is it?  Using migrations?  Where are your mappings for these types?

Comment: I am using automatic migration right now to try and quickly setup this database.

Comment: You should be using mappings to tell EF how the two types are related.  Are you not doing that?  And, if not, EF *strongly* uses "conventions" to figure out what you are doing.  Appending "FK" on the end of a property name **does not qualify**.  If you want to let EF figure things out (e.g., not use mappings) then you need to follow the conventions described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: So how do I create the mappings? I have added `[ForeignKey("CompanyPK")]` to ApplicationUser and nothing changes.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping EF works, but it won't always work the way you want it to. It's not quite the framework to use if you want purdy databases.  I have to use it, and am not exactly happy with it.  I'd prefer to design my tables and types and use Dapper, if any ORM.

Comment: EF6 has another way to map types. I think the Gu's blog post style is still available, but there's a different way where you extend a particular type and create the mapping in that type's constructor.  You can find out how by searching for ef6 mappings. Ya get stuff like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872483/entity-framework-mapping

Comment: I want to do this in code, and I don't want to write out all the mappings. The e-framework cannot understand that I changed the names because NameID isn't my style, I used data attributes, and it still creates a badly designed database.

Comment: Again, EF either uses mappings, or conventions. If you don't want an ugly database, then you have to use one or the other. That's just the way it's going to be. Now, go forth and slice like a hammer. Good luck!

Comment: I might have found a solution in the documentation for data attributes.